# Does the 'Mafia' still exist in Italy?

Tags: criminology, italy, organized-crime

[Here is a claim](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120215191119AAzXGPD) that says the mafia still exist in Italy:

> Yes, sadly it does, and will ever does. I'm Italian.
>   and it's not called mob.. or whatever.
>   there are many clans, in several Italian cities.. and you could call all them "Mafia"
>   Source(s):
>   italian

Is there any evidence to support or deny this claim?

Comment: no doubt depends on your definition of "mafia". It's now often used to mean any organised criminal group with a strict hierarchy, no doubt those exist...

Comment: Would the fact that Italian tribunals have special ["anti-mafia" sections](http://www.giustizia.it/giustizia/it/mg_2_10_1.wp) be enough proof? Also, let's not forget [what](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giovanni_Falcone) [happened](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paolo_Borsellino) not too long ago...

Comment: Yes, it still exists but other organizations are active in Italy as well. The DIA (Direzione Investigativa Antimafia) is the structure created by the State to fight these groups and, until this structure exists, Mafia existence is acknowledged. [About DIA](http://www.interno.gov.it/dip_ps/dia/page/competenze.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes it does exist.**

> A 10-year investigation by Italian authorities earlier this year
>   revealed ties between Italian groups and Mexican drug traffickers to
>   move shipments of cocaine across the Atlantic Ocean.

[Italian mafia smuggles cocaine for europe](http://latino.foxnews.com/latino/news/2012/06/21/mexico-drug-cartels-supply-italian-mafia-with-cocaine-for-europe/)

The Italian mafia, have its ups and downs. The bosses and high-ups get caught, their business broken down, when the government makes a major crackdown on the mafia. What usually seems to be the case is that not all of the mafia is arrested, and then with the void left by the mafia bosses, others takes the chance to rise to power.

> By the late 1990s, the weakened Cosa Nostra had to yield most of the
>   illegal drug trade to the 'Ndrangheta crime organization from
>   Calabria. In 2006, the latter was estimated to control 80% of the
>   cocaine imported to Europe. In 2012, it's been reported that Mafia
>   have joined forces with the Mexican drug cartels.

[Wikipedia about ups and downs of Sicilian Mafia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosa_Nostra)

What seems to be the case is that there always is some sort of illegal source of money, which maintains the mafia. Cocaine, Heroin, protection racketeering etc. This leads to a slow rise back, with the mafia slowly growing up in power, even after major crackdowns when majority of the mafia have been taken care of.

As with all business, as long as it is doing well it keeps on growing. Sadly it's true for criminal business as well.

Comment: Also, don't forget the two other big fields of mafia action: building and politics

Comment: Yea I saw some claims of Silvio Berlusconi being related to the mafia, like they helped him getting into power, and now demand things of him. That actually is an interesting question.

Comment: other very notable cases exist, such as that of Giulio Andreotti